# How i can calculate the correlation between groups in R using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, correlation

Let's say i have data frame in R that looks like this :

```
var = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3),rep("C",3),rep("D",3),rep("E",3))
y = rnorm(15)
data = tibble(var,y);data
```

With output:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 2
   var        y
   <chr>  <dbl>
 1 A     -1.23 
 2 A     -0.983
 3 A      1.28 
 4 B     -0.268
 5 B     -0.460
 6 B     -1.23 
 7 C      1.87 
 8 C      0.416
 9 C     -1.99 
10 D      0.289
11 D      1.70 
12 D     -0.455
13 E     -0.648
14 E      0.376
15 E     -0.887
```

i want to calculate the correlation of each distinct pair in R using dplyr.
Ideally i want to look like this (the third column to contain the values of each correlation pair):

| var1 | var2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | cor(A,B) |
| A | C | cor(A,C) |
| A | D | cor(A,D) |
| A | E | cor(A,E) |
| B | C | cor(B,E) |
| B | D | cor(B,E) |
| B | E | cor(B,E) |
| C | D | cor(C,E) |
| C | E | cor(C,E) |
| D | E | cor(D,E) |

How i can do that in R ?
Any help ?

**Additional**

if i have another grouping variable say group2:

```
var2 = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3),rep("C",3),rep("D",3),rep("E",3),rep("F",3),
        rep("H",3),rep("I",3))

y2 = rnorm(24)
group2 = c(rep(1,6),rep(2,6),rep(3,6),rep(1,6))
data2 = tibble(var2,group2,y2);data2
```

which ideally must look like this :

| group | var1 | var2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | cor(A,B) |
| 1 | A | H | cor(A,H) |
| 1 | A | I | cor(A,I) |
| 1 | B | H | cor(B,H) |
| 1 | B | I | cor(B,I) |
| 1 | H | I | cor(H,I) |
| 2 | C | D | cor(C,D) |
| 3 | E | F | cor(E,F) |

How i can calculate each variable in column var2 on each group group2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Add an index column 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ... and then use read.zoo to convert from long to wide.  Take the correlation reshape back to long form using as.data.frame.table and filter out the desired rows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

DF %>%
  mutate(index = sequence(rle(var)$lengths)) %>%
  read.zoo(index = "index", split = "var") %>%
  cor %>%
  as.data.frame.table(responseName = "cor") %>%
  filter(format(Var1) < format(Var2))
```

**2)** At the expense of one more line of code we can substitute pivot_wider for read.zoo.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>%
  mutate(index = sequence(rle(var)$lengths)) %>%
  pivot_wider(index, names_from = "var", values_from = "y") %>%
  select(-index) %>%
  cor %>%
  as.data.frame.table(responseName = "cor") %>%
  filter(format(Var1) < format(Var2))
```

**3)** A base solution consists of using combn to get the pairs of var with the indicated function f.

```
co <- combn(unique(DF$var), 2)
f <- function(v) with(DF, data.frame(t(v), cor = cor(y[var==v[1]], y[var==v[2]])))
do.call("rbind", apply(co, 2, f))
```

**4)** We can use list comprehensions via several alternative packages.

```
library(listcompr)

with(DF,
  gen.data.frame(list(x_1, x_2, cor = cor(y[var == x_1], y[var == x_2])),
    x_ = unique(var), x_1 < x_2)
)
```

or

```
library(comprehenr)

with(DF, {
  uv <- unique(var)
  to_df(for(u in uv) for(v in uv) if (u < v) 
    data.frame(u, v, cor = cor(y[var == u], y[var == v])))
})
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form.

```
DF <-
structure(list(var = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E"), y = c(-1.23, -0.983, 1.28, 
-0.268, -0.46, -1.23, 1.87, 0.416, -1.99, 0.289, 1.7, -0.455, 
-0.648, 0.376, -0.887)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15"))
```

Comment: thank you very much for your useful question.What modifications must be done in order to solve  as well  the additional problem ?

Comment: I will make another post about that.Leave it.

Comment: Suppose we add a group column to the DF defined in the answer as follows.  Then for (1) and similarly for (2) we can use group_modify:  `DF$group <- rep(1:2, c(9, 6));
library(dplyr);
library(zoo);
DF %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  group_modify(~ {
    mutate(., index = sequence(rle(var)$lengths)) %>%
    read.zoo(index = "index", split = "var") %>%
    cor %>%
    as.data.frame.table(responseName = "cor") %>%
    filter(format(Var1) < format(Var2))
  }) %>%
  ungroup`

Comment: Your answers are very useful and thanks a lot for your help. Final on: if instead the cor the function was the quantile of a pairwise difference how can be written ? For example quantile(A-B,0.99).

Comment: In (3) change f appropriately to use quantile.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(var) %>% 
  group_map(~ data.frame(.x) %>% set_names(.y)) %>% 
  bind_cols %>% cor %>% 
  {data.frame(row=rownames(.)[row(.)[upper.tri(.)]], 
              col=colnames(.)[col(.)[upper.tri(.)]], 
              corr=.[upper.tri(.)])}

#>    row col       corr
#> 1    A   B -0.9949738
#> 2    A   C -0.9574502
#> 3    B   C  0.9815368
#> 4    A   D -0.7039708
#> 5    B   D  0.6293137
#> 6    C   D  0.4690460
#> 7    A   E -0.5755463
#> 8    B   E  0.4907660
#> 9    C   E  0.3150499
#> 10   D   E  0.9859711
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.Is there any way of how i can calculate the addition task in the OP?Thanks again for your effort.

Comment: That is not very clear to me what you aim at with the edited part, @HomerJaySimpson. Could you please elaborate more upon that? Do you mean to obtain the same correlations dataframe with an additional column for correlation regarding `var2`?

Comment: I made an edit in the OP.You are right.It was  unclear before

Comment: I guess something is wrong, as `var2` in your data does not have any `H`, @HomerJaySimpson...

Comment: it has.Seems very strange

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one-liner via base R

```
data.frame(t(combn(unique(data$var), 2, function(i)
                     list(v1 = i[[1]], 
                          v2 = i[[2]], 
                          value = cor(data$y[data$var %in% i[[1]]], 
                                      data$y[data$var %in% i[[2]]])))))

   X1 X2         X3
1   A  B   0.997249
2   A  C  0.7544987
3   A  D -0.7924587
4   A  E 0.03567887
5   B  C  0.8010711
6   B  D -0.7450683
7   B  E  0.1096579
8   C  D -0.1976141
9   C  E  0.6828033
10  D  E  0.5812632
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.Is there any way of how i can calculate the addition task in the OP?Thanks again for your effort.

Comment: Your example (data2) throws error

Comment: i fixed it.Can you try it now ?